# Download file from AppHarbor

Tags: appharbor

I use [AppHarbor](https://appharbor.com/) to set my website, when I change something in the website (upload image) I write the change in a XML file. The path of the image, name, id, etc.

How I can see this XML File that I write on the server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't use the web worker filesystems on AppHarbor for persistence. This is because changes are lost when a new version of your code is deployed or if AppHarbor has to do maintenance on your app. Also, if your app uses multiple web workers, filesystem changes are not synced between instances. Use Amazon S3 instead or one of the [data persistence add-ons offered](https://appharbor.com/addons).